# Want some information on youtube API's filters on PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am trying to fetch YouTube videos through filters, I've purchased a plugin for it. In youtube when we select a filter, let say you select "HD" it will redirect you to main page with that filter and so on. Mean to say we can't select multiple filters at a time. What I am trying to do is to get filters in checkbox so we can select multiple filters at a time, and also we can search by multiple keywords. Let say if I write "Black Car" in youtube, it will show me data related to black car. But I wanna treat them as individually. is this possible? if yes, please help me how. I'va purchased "PHP Video Search Engine" by codefir | CodeCanyon. This is the link. 
*codecanyon.net/item/php-video-search-engine/3123910* This script is using YouTube Data API v3

Comment: Please specify what plugin(s) you are using, how your set-up is and where (what software) you do the search. Also share your code, this will clarify a lot. Try to follow the guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I'va purchased "PHP Video Search Engine" codefir | CodeCanyon. This is the link.
https://codecanyon.net/item/php-video-search-engine/3123910
This script is using YouTube Data API v3

Comment: You should edit your question with this information.

Comment: thanks. I've rewrite my question